# Event emitter shared between modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I use event emitter and it seems that I need it in several module,
I mean I want to use the **same instance** my question is weather its better to create one module which expose the event emitter instance and how its recommended to do it?

What I did is like following which I share between modules but not sure if its recommended ...please let me know

```
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

module.exports = {
    getEventEmitter: function () {
        return eventEmitter;
    }
};
```

Comment: i think you should take a look here: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Comment: @alexey already done it...

Comment: hm, so what the problem? you can pass it through module.exports

Comment: @alexey - please see my update

Comment: if it works i think it will be better to move this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could equally just have done `module.exports = new (require('events').EventEmitter);` in one line, without that unnecessary getter function, but it's fine.

Comment: @Bergi - thank you but the shorter way will not create the instance in every call (with the new keyword) ?

Comment: @shopiaT: Modules are not called, they are required. It's instantiated only once. The `new` call is in the same context as it is in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is fine.

It could be simplified like this, if you want:

```
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

module.exports = eventEmitter;
```

Note that while this generally works fine (I do this a lot), [it is possible to break the `require` module cache](http://derickbailey.com/2016/03/09/creating-a-true-singleton-in-node-js-with-es6-symbols/) and end up with a different instance.

Comment: i'm doing it in the same way across the projects